# Interface implements a different interface, causing issues binding to Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, data-binding, interface

I am learning Fluent NHibernate and this issue arose from that project.

I have a base Class and a base Interface:

```
public abstract class Base : IBase
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsValid()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public interface IBase
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    bool IsValid();
}
```

which I inherit all of my other Domain classes from:

```
public class Item:Base, IItem
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        <snip>
    }
    <snip>
}

public interface IItem: IBase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    <snip>
}
```

However when I try and bind a list of all Items to a winforms Combobox I get an error.

```
        var ds = from i in GetSession().Linq<IItem>() select i;
        cmbItems.DataSource = ds.ToArray();

        this.cmbItems.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.cmbItems.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I get an error:

> Cannot bind to the new value member.
>   Parameter name: value

I have figured out that this occurs because I am implementing IBase on IItem. If I modify IItem it works fine.

```
public interface IItem: IBase
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    <snip>
    bool IsValid();
}
```

So beyond the practical, just make it work, am I doing interfaces correctly? Should I not have interfaces implement other interfaces? If I should have IItem implement IBase, is there a way to bind properly to a Winforms control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's because WinForms binding system is based on the use of `TypeDescriptor`, and `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(IItem))` returns only the declared properties... So the `ComboBox` finds `Name` because it's declared in `IItem`, but not `Id`.

To work around this problem, you could create an anonymous type with the properties you need:

```
    var ds = from i in GetSession().Linq<IItem>() select new { i.Id, i.Name };
    cmbItems.DataSource = ds.ToArray();

    this.cmbItems.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.cmbItems.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Anyway, I don't think you should redeclare `Id` and `IsValid` in `IItem`, because it would hide the properties declared in `IBase` (the compiler gives you a warning when you do that)

Comment: I tried doing an anonymous type, but I get an error "Object must implement IConvertible", at ds.ToArray(); Any idea's?

Comment: It works fine for me, using a collection rather than a NHibernate query... I think it's because `Linq<T>` returns an `IQueryable<T>`, so it tries to execute the projection in SQL. Try to replace `Linq<IItem>()` with `Linq<IItem>().AsEnumerable()`