# Error when binding listbox to a list of objects (nested interfaces)

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, interface

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IIdentifiable
{
    object Id { get; }
}
public interface IIdentifiable<T>: IIdentifiable
{
    new T Id { get; }
}
public interface IItem: IIdentifiable<Guid>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to bind a listbox to a list of items like:

```
lbItems.DataSource = list;     // List<IItem> here
lbItems.DisplayMember = "Name";
lbItems.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I get error: "Cannot bind to the new value member. Parameter name: value"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must thank to the guys from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524676/interface-implements-a-different-interface-causing-issues-binding-to-combobox?rq=1).

> WinForms binding system is based on the use of `TypeDescriptor`, and
>   `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(IItem))` returns only the
>   declared properties... So the `ComboBox` finds `Name` because it's
>   declared in `IItem`, but not `Id`.

To work around this problem, I had to create an anonymous type by projecting each item of the list.

This was the final code:

```
lbItems.DataSource = list.Select(item => new { item.Id, item.Name }).ToList();
lbItems.DisplayMember = "Name";
lbItems.ValueMember = "Id";
```