# Does winforms databinding on combobox only work on classes and not on interfaces?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, .net-4.8

After a period of banging my head against various objects within my reach I found a behaviour that does not suit my needs, and I want to check if I miss something.

Consider a form with one combobox (`combobox1`), one label (`label1`), one textbox (`textbox1`) and two buttons (you guessed it, `button1` and `button2`).

Some housekeeping first:

My convenience-class for adding stuff to ListControls:

```
public class ListControlItem<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    Func<T, string> DisplayFunction;
    public string Display { get { return DisplayFunction.Invoke(Value); } }

    public ListControlItem(T theValue, Func<T, string> theDisplayFunction)
    {
        Value = theValue;
        DisplayFunction = theDisplayFunction;
    }

    public static void SetupListControl(ListControl lc)
    {
        lc.DisplayMember = nameof(Display);
        lc.ValueMember = nameof(Value);
    }
}
```

An interface which will become relevant shortly:

```
interface Idemointerface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int SpecificValue { get; set; }
}
```

And a class implementing said interface:

```
class demoClass : Idemointerface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SpecificValue { get; set; }

    public demoClass(string name, int specValue)
    {
        Name = name;
        SpecificValue = specValue;
    }
}
```

Of course we need a class that will eventually be bound to:

```
class demoWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    demoClass selectedDemo;
    public demoClass SelectedDemo
    {
        get { return selectedDemo == null ? (TemplateDemos.Any() ? TemplateDemos.First().Value : null) : selectedDemo; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedDemo == null || !selectedDemo.Equals(value))
            {
                selectedDemo = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedDemo)));
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SpecificText)));
            }
        }
    }

    public string SpecificText { get { return SelectedDemo == null ? "" : $"{SelectedDemo.Name}: {SelectedDemo.SpecificValue}"; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BindingList<ListControlItem<demoClass>> TemplateDemos { get; private set; }

    public demoWrapper()
    {
        TemplateDemos = new BindingList<ListControlItem<demoClass>>();
        selectedDemo = null;
    }

    public void SetTemplates(IEnumerable<demoClass> files)
    {
        selectedDemo = null;
        TemplateDemos.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        TemplateDemos.Clear();
        foreach (demoClass nf in files)
            TemplateDemos.Add(new ListControlItem<demoClass>(nf, new Func<demoClass, string>(v => v.Name)));

        TemplateDemos.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        TemplateDemos.ResetBindings();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedDemo)));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SpecificText)));
    }
}
```

Note, that the Property `SelectedDemo` and everything associated with it is of the type of the concrete class and not of the interface!

And finally the UI code to mush it all together:

```
public partial class frm_Combobox : Form
{
    BindingSource bsWrapper;
    demoWrapper wrapper;
    public frm_Combobox()
    {
        wrapper = new demoWrapper();
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupBinding();
    }

    private void SetupBinding()
    {
        bsWrapper = new BindingSource();
        bsWrapper.DataSource = typeof(demoWrapper);

        ListControlItem<demoClass>.SetupListControl(comboBox1);
        comboBox1.DataSource = wrapper.TemplateDemos;
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(comboBox1.SelectedValue), bsWrapper, nameof(demoWrapper.SelectedDemo));
        label1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(label1.Text), bsWrapper, nameof(demoWrapper.SpecificText));

        bsWrapper.DataSource = wrapper;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wrapper.SetTemplates(new demoClass[] { new demoClass("test1", 1), new demoClass("test2", 2) });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wrapper.SetTemplates(new demoClass[] { new demoClass("test11", 11), new demoClass("test22", 22), new demoClass("test33", 33) });
    }
}
```

**Now to the actual problem:**

The above code results in the desired behaviour. Upon loading the form, one can click on either button to set the list of "templates" inside the combobox. The list will be updated and the selected item defaults to the first one in the list. Selecting a different item in the combobox is possible and clicking inside of the textbox (after selecting a different combobox-element) moves the focus away from the combobox and thus sets the `SelectedDemo`-property in the wrapper class. The label updates its text accordingly. **This behaviour is what I would expect and what I want to have**

**But:** exchanging the type for `SelectedDemo` (and associates) to `Idemointerface` breaks everything. I can still update the list inside of the box, but upon selecting a new item and moving focus away from the combobox, the box resets itself to the first item. The setter for `SelectedDemo` does *not* get called.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524925) answer states, that binding in winforms works with using the `TypeDescriptor`, but I have no idea how I can exploit this to make everything work again. The only solution I can think of (and which I am going to implement now) is adding jet another wrapper around the interface, so I have a concrete class that can be properly bound.

**Why does binding behave the way it does with interfaces?** (and no, overriding `Equals` and implemening `IEquatable<Idemoclass>` to help with checking which object is selected does not work)